# Bootstrap timepicker add hours to default time

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, timepicker

I am using bootstrap-timepicker (https://jdewit.github.io/bootstrap-timepicker/) for 2 inputs: `start_date` and `end_date`. As I see the start date has a default and is the closest :00 or :30 minute. I want the `end_date` to have by default the closest :00 or :30 minute + 1 hour. How can I achieve this?

```
    $('.timepicker-input-end').timepicker({
        showInputs: false,
        defaultTime: ????
    });
```

Comment: Use different id's for each  time picker.

Comment: I already did this as you see I have `timepicker-input-end` class so I only referring to the end input. The problem is how I set the closest :30 or :00 plus 1 hour?

Comment: I had used "bootstrap-datetimepicker" for one of my project. It's worked fine. (start_date and end_date)

Comment: @IonVasile I've updated answer please see if works

Answer (score 3):

It should be simple if you have javascript date object:

```
var defDate = new Date ();
// you can do 00 or 30 min logic here
defDate.setHours(defDate.getHours() + 1);
$('.timepicker-input-end').timepicker({
    showInputs: false,
    defaultTime: defDate.toString("hh:mm tt")
});
```

Update: because you use timepicker with 12 hour format you can use [datejs](http://www.datejs.com/) to convert time easily.

Comment: What do you think?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38435030/bootstrap-timepicker-add-hours-to-default-time/38436061#38436061

Comment: with datejs it's more beautiful

Comment: I just did not include adding 1 hour with one line, u can modify easily

Answer (score 1):

I fount this the simplest solution, I forgot that fullcalendar library use moment.

```
    $('.timepicker-input-end').timepicker({
        showInputs: false,
        defaultTime: moment($('input[name="appointment[start_time]"]').val(), "hh:mm TT").add(30, 'minutes').format("hh:mm A")
    });
```

What do you think?

Answer (score 0):

```
var currentDate = new Date();
        var day = currentDate.getDate();
        var month = currentDate.getMonth() + 1;
        var year = currentDate.getFullYear();
        todayDateReport = year + "-" + month + "-" + day;
        $("#currentDate").html(todayDateReport);
        startDate = todayDateReport + " 00:00:00";
        endDate =   todayDateReport + " 01:00:00";

        $("#startDateInput").val(startDate);
        $("#endDateInput").val(endDate);
$('#startDate').datetimepicker({
         format: 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss',
         collapse:false,
         sideBySide:true,
         useCurrent:false,
         showClose:true,
         maxDate : currentDate
     });

     $('#endDate').datetimepicker({
         format: 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss',
         collapse:false,
         sideBySide:true,
         useCurrent:false,
         showClose:true,
     });
```

Comment: I am not using `datetimepicker`, only `timepicker`